# Adding libraries in Spyder

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, spyder, environment

I installed the libraries I needed by using these commands below:

conda install matplotlib

conda install numpy

I see the '# All requested packages already installed.' in terminal. But when I try to run the code again, I get this warning: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.pylot'

Can somebody help me how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely occurring because the environment in which you installed the packages is not the one set as interpreter in spyder. See how to change interpreter in spyder [here](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#:%7E:text=To%20work%20with%20an%20existing,in%20the%20Python%20interpreter%20section.)